# trigger function on separate window using intercom.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, intercom.js

When trying to use [intercom.js](https://github.com/diy/intercom.js) I can print what my message is to the log in line 21 of the index file

```
intercom.on('notice', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $messages.append($('<p>').text(data.message));
    document.title = '(' + $messages[0].childNodes.length + ') ' + title;
});
```

Is there any way when clicking it simply to trigger an alert on the other page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [read me file](https://github.com/diy/intercom.js/blob/master/README.md) it gives you a basic code

```
// run this in multiple tabs!
var intercom = Intercom.getInstance();

intercom.on('notice', function(data) {
    console.log(data.message);
});

intercom.emit('notice', {message: 'Hello, all windows!'});
```

Put the emit code on the page with the button, put the on code on the page where you want the alert to appear [of course change the console line to an alert.]

---

So making the alert happen would be:

**Page 1 [Page with the alert]:**

```
var intercom = Intercom.getInstance();

intercom.on('notice', function(data) {
    alert(data.message);
});
```

**Page 2 [Page with the button]:**

```
function broadcast () {
    var intercom = Intercom.getInstance();   
    intercom.emit('notice', {message: 'Hello, all windows!'});
}
document.getElementById("myButtonId").addEventListener("click", broadcast , false);
```

Comment: That works brilliantly. Thanks so much. Was totally above my head, but this makes sense. Thanks!